# Is it possible to implicitly style a WPF ListView in GridView mode?

Tags: wpf, styles, skinning

I can easily "implicitly" style a ListView in basic (non-GridView) mode but my attempts to implicitly style a ListView in GridView mode have failed miserably. The below works because I explicity set the Style and ItemContainerStyle of the second ListView.  If you remove those two settings, the second ListView does not get implicitly styled liked the first one does.  It seems that a basic ListView needs a ContentPresenter and a GridView ListView needs a GridViewRowPresenter.

Am I runnning into a WPF brick wall here? Is this even possible?  If not, it makes creating an application skin less robust because now your users have to know to explicitly set the Style and ItemContainerStyle on ListViews that display in GridView mode.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ListView">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Lime"/>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
              <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <Grid>
                      <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentHost" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
              </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="{x:Static GridView.GridViewStyleKey}"
               TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Lime"/>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="{x:Static GridView.GridViewItemContainerStyleKey}"
               TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListView x:Name="_listView1">
            <system:String>Item 1</system:String>
            <system:String>Item 2</system:String>
            <system:String>Item 3</system:String>
        </ListView>

        <ListView x:Name="_listView2" Grid.Column="1" 
                  Style="{StaticResource {x:Static GridView.GridViewStyleKey}}"
                  ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource {x:Static GridView.GridViewItemContainerStyleKey}}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Date"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Day of Week" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DayOfWeek}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Year" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Year}" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
            <system:DateTime>1/1/2010</system:DateTime>
            <system:DateTime>1/1/2011</system:DateTime>
            <system:DateTime>1/1/2012</system:DateTime>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: It's probably a little late coming, but I was trying to answer another question, and found a workaround that may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18700352/listviewitem-override-default-style-break-gridviews/18775166#18775166

Comment: Convert that to an answer and I'll mark it as such. Thanks!

Comment: Done, glad it was useful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into the same odd/tricky problem as you're describing above, and ran into a blog post that suggested a neat little hack/fix which seems to provide the behaviour you're after. The main points are repeated in case the link dies.

You've already described the odd requirements for `ListView` styling if you want to cover views with and that make use of `GridViews`; a basic `ListView` needs a `ContentPresenter`, a `GridView ListView needs` a `GridViewRowPresenter`.

The poster managed to get around this by including both presenters within his style, and using a `Setter` to show the `ContentPresenter` only when required.

So your `ControlTemplate` could implement something along these lines (with your extra styling properties added as required):

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <!-- Pair of presenters -->
    <Grid>
        <GridViewRowPresenter x:Name="gridrowPresenter"
                Content="{TemplateBinding Property=ContentControl.Content}"/>
        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter"
                Content="{TemplateBinding Property=ContentControl.Content}"  Visibility="Collapsed"/>
    </Grid>
    <!-- Visibility Controlling Setter -->
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="GridView.ColumnCollection" Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter TargetName="contentPresenter" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Both `GridViewRowPresenter` and `ContentPresenter` are present in the style, but the `ContentPresenter` is hidden (`Visibility="Collapsed"`).

The neat trick is the use of a `Trigger` on `GridView.ColumnCollection`; if this value is null (which occurs when the `GridViewRowPresenter` has no content), the `ContentPresenter` will be made visible, correctly displaying your normal `ListView` content). The `GridViewRowPresenter` will have no content, so it won't display any conflicting visuals.

If the `GridView` has content, it will be displayed (providing the correct row formatting), and the `ContentPresenter` will remain hidden.

Original blog entry: http://www.steelyeyedview.com/2010/03/contentpresenter-gridviewrowpresenter.html